# Urldecode scandinavian ascii values

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, converters, urldecode

I need help with decoding url encoded scandinavian ASCII values with PHP.

I have tried decode å character like this:

```
$string = "%e5";
echo rawurldecode($string);
```

But this gives black diamond �. Same result with urldecode() function.

I am using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">` in head.

When using rawurldecode() function on English letters like %61 it works great.
See http://www.backbone.se/urlencodingUTF8.htm for all url encoded ASCII codes.

Comment: does it work when you set the string to `%C3%A5`?

Comment: Yes, it works with %C3%A5. I been stuck with this strange problem for hours..
This online tool gives the same bad result https://www.functions-online.com/rawurldecode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`E5` is the ISO-8859-1 encoded representation of the character å.

Your problem is that you're outputting an ISO-8859-1 encoded string, yet are telling the browser to interpret it as UTF-8. Either change the encoding in your HTTP headers/meta tag, or convert the string from 8859 to UTF-8:

```
echo utf8_encode(rawurldecode('%e5'));
```

<sub>(There's almost never a good time for `utf8_encode`, but in this case it actually succinctly performs the needed charset conversion. Usually you should prefer explicit charset conversions using `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding`.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much deceze! Dankeschön!
How do you know its ISO-8859-1? Are there any websites to search?

Comment: It must be a *single byte encoding*, since only a single byte is used to encode the character. UTF-8 would use two bytes for this character. ISO-8859-1 is the most used single-byte encoding, so it was my first guess. A quick lookup in its table confirmed it. – Unless you have this experience/intuition, you'll simply have to look through all encoding tables to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I had been lost in a encoding jungle without your help.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 0):

utf-8 character set does not contain e5 code.

Please check a table with utf-8 charset .
Try with a valid utf-8 string.

"scandinavian ascii" character set is not supported by rawurldecode .

Try one of the functions iconv,that support CP865 (I guess this is the character set for which you want support):

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.iconv-mime-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.iconv-mime-decode-headers.php

Comment: Thanks! I tried `iconv('CP865', 'UTF-8', $string); ` function with bad luck.

Comment: not iconv,because you have url-encoded CP865 while iconv expects byte encoded,not url encoded.

You could also write a function to decode url-encoded CP865,the character set is small and it will not be too hard.